# Get similar part of string array items

Tags: java, string

I have an array of Strings:

```
qTrees[0] = "023012311312201123123130110332";
qTrees[1] = "023012311130023103123130110332";
qTrees[2] = "023013200020123103123130110333";
qTrees[3] = "023013200202301123123130110333";
```

Using this cycle I'm trying to retrieve similar part from them:

```
String similarPart = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < qTrees[0].length(); i++){
        if (qTrees[0].charAt(i) == qTrees[1].charAt(i) &&
                qTrees[1].charAt(i) == qTrees[2].charAt(i) &&
                qTrees[2].charAt(i) == qTrees[3].charAt(i) ){

            similarPart += qTrees[0].charAt(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

But this is wrong. As you see it will return only "02301", but the deeper similarity is possible.

Please suggest me a better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: The cycle returning the 02301, but as you see from this example for two pairs of strings there can be two deeper resuls: "023012311" and "023013200". But it's correct only for this example. There also can be different more unique strings and only 1 correct result.

Comment: So the similarity only has to be between at least 2 strings?

Comment: It's depends.
Here is another example:
qTrees[0] = "023012011312201123123130110332";
qTrees[1] = "023012121130023103123130110332";
qTrees[2] = "023012200020123103123130110333";
qTrees[3] = "023012310202301123123130110333";
Here the correct result is : "023012" and you can go deeper.

Comment: I'm still not following at all. And shouldn't `312313011033` be the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to better define what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want to:

- find the longest common starting sequence between any two entries in the array;
- find the longest common starting sequence across all of the entries in the array;
- find the longest common sequence (i.e. same characters in same position) between any two entries;
- find the longest common sequence across all entries in the array.

All of these will give slightly different approaches, but it will all boil down to correctly using `break` and `continue` in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else part in your code. Then it will check until the end of the string.

The code :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < qTrees[0].length(); i++){
        if (qTrees[0].charAt(i) == qTrees[1].charAt(i) &&
                qTrees[1].charAt(i) == qTrees[2].charAt(i) &&
                qTrees[2].charAt(i) == qTrees[3].charAt(i) ){

            similarPart += qTrees[0].charAt(i);
        }
    }
```